# Global file access with suPHP

Tags: php, apache, permissions, suphp

I need users to have read only access to global files. Currently I add a symlink to the global files into the user directories. This seems to work until I access a file within the symlinked directory. At that time, I receive the following errors until I make the file owners/group match.

```
SoftException in Application.cpp:422: Mismatch between target UID (1067) and UID (99) of file
```

I've read a few [forums posts](http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/suphp-symbolic-links-reseller-account-212102.html) without a definite answer.

How can I accomplish this, ideally without compromising security?